The rig is not parenting correctly
I have this model of V1 (From Ultra Kill). And I'm learning how to rig. I had followed a couple of tutorials but it has come to my attention the rig does not parent to the object properly. the mesh does not move correctly.
I have clicked the mesh > Clicked the armature > ctrl + p > With Automatic Weight
Could somebody please help?
 
Blender File


Hello please share your file

@moonboots added the file

You have overlapping vertices, apply the scale and rotation of your armature and object, select the whole mesh in Edit mode and Merge by Distance (M) with a Merge DIstance of 0.005 and parent With Automatic Weights.
